# Sample question on the about page

Tags: discussion, scope

The ["about"-page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/about) has been redesigned, which I find a good idea. It comes with a sample question, [Required Vaccinations in Eastern Europe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/required-vaccinations-for-eastern-europe), although the accepted answer in the example and the actual answer are different (the real accepted answer is much better).

Is there a better Q/A pair that doesn't need editing before being put onto the "about"-page?

Interestingly, the [most upvoted non-toilet questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) are about general advice rather than specific issues (as in: how do I get by ferry from A to B). Is that the type of questions we would want new users to ask?

Comment: Moderators can see a list of permissible questions at http://travel.stackexchange.com/admin/about/choose-question . The requirements unfortunately exclude many good Q/A pairs: the posts must be almost devoid of markup and must be short. Moderators can select the question but not the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better Q/A pair that doesn't need editing before being put onto the "about"-page?

Yes. At present the example is [Do EU residents need visa to travel to USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85022/do-eu-residents-need-visa-to-travel-to-usa). Based on comparing votes and answers, this is a much better choice.

> Is that the type of questions we would want new users to ask?

"How do I get by ferry from A to B" is a better question type than many others deemed on topic here, so Yes. See for example [Vancouver to Seattle by Ferry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6876/vancouver-to-seattle-by-ferry).